# How to use check something before an error is raised

Tags: ruby, rspec3

I have the following ruby code

```
class Gateway
...
 def post
  begin 
  ...
  raise ClientError if state == :open
  rescue ClientError => e
   Log.add("error")
   raise
  end
 end
end
```

On RSpec, how can I  check that when `ClientError` is raised `Log.add` is called?

I have tried different things but I always get the error raised.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't check that *"check that when `ClientError` is raised `Log.add` is called"*. You should check that when the `state` is `:open`, you get the error logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
describe '#post' do
  context 'with state :open' do
    let(:gateway) { Gateway.new(state: :open) }

    it 'logs the error' do
      expect(Log).to receive(:add).with('error')
      gateway.post rescue nil
    end

    it 're-raises the error' do
      expect { gateway.post }.to raise_error(ClientError)
    end
  end
end
```

In the first example, `rescue nil` ensures that your spec is not failing because of the raised error (it silently rescues it). The second example checks that the error is being re-raised.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was missing the `rescue nil`. I prefer having the 2 separate specs.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably do something like this (the initialize step might need to look bit different, depending on how you need to set the `state` to `:open`):

```
describe 'Gateway#post' do
  let(:gateway) { Gateway.new(state: :open) }

  before { allow(Log).to receive(:add) }

  it 'raises an excpetion' do
    expect { gateway.post }.to raise_error(ClientError)
    expect(Log).to have_received(:add).with('error')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.